# Is there a config file for telnet that's similar to .ssh/config?

Tags: linux, telnet

I constantly need to type some hostnames / IPs to telnet, and sadly they don't support ssh.

Is there a config file for telnet similar to ssh? I don't have admin access to change the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: What is it that you're wanting to configure? What is it that can be configured in ssh which overrides / is equivalent to the data in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

telnet reads from ~/.telnetrc at startup, but that won't help you with typing long hostnames.  For that you should make yourself some shell functions like this:

```
t1 () { telnet foo.bar.blat; }
t2 () { telnet crock.fook.ack; }
t3 () { ... and so on... }
```

Put them in your .bashrc, or .zshrc or whatever your shell reads at startup and then type `t1` when you need to telnet to foo.bar.blat.

Comment: You can also use `alias` for simple cases like this. `alias t1="telnet foo.bar.blat"`, etc.